# Que signifie l'expression « met la maisonnée sens dessus dessous » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Est-ce que quelqu’un pourrait clarifier le sens de « met la maisonnée sens dessus dessous » ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **`"sens dessus dessous"`** (note the `"sens"` and not `"sans"`), and it may mean literally `"upside down"`, or metaphorically `"a shambles"`.

`"la maisonnée"` will be the house, or more specifically the house content. And, as stated by Circeaus, it might be the people in the house and convey a more emotional meaning. We would need more context to have a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Make a mess of the place", but here it can also mean emotionally, as *maisonnée* is often used as proxy for "family" (its original meaning is "household").